# how to get value by an input in one textbox from another column the same row

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, client-server

i've have an html file with two textboxes
1.orders
1.amount
i want that when i type a number in the orders text box
i will get the value from another column in my Google Sheet in the same row that match to to this order

**this is my Code.gs code its not working**

```
    function doGet(e) {
  
 return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('page');
}




function getCost(oneCode){
  
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1333t7lvECnmOcCnTE6gnn_RN1wrPckWpIETiPUjkUnU/edit#gid=0";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data = ws.getRange(1,1,ws.getLastRow(),2).getValues();
  
  var ordersList = data.map(function(r){ return r[0]; });
  var amountList = data.map(function(r){ return r[1]; });
  
  
  var position = ordersLis.indexOf(oneCode);
  if(position > -1){
    return amountList[position];
 
  } else {
    return "not found";
    
  }
  
}
```

========================
**this the html code**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <script>
  document.getElementById("one").addEventlistener("input",doThis);
  
  function doThis(){
  
  var oneCode = document.getElementById("one").value;
  
  
  
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateAmount).getCost(oneCode);
  
  }
  
  function updateAmount(cost){
  
  document.getElementById("two").value = cost;
  
  }
  
  </script>
  <body>
  <div>
    <input id="one" type="text">
    <label for="one">orders</label>
    </div>
    <div>
    <input disabled id="two" type="text">
    <label for="two">amount</label>
    </div>
    
    
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: those are 2 columns i want to find a match from left to right]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to propose the following modification.

### Modification points:

- At HTML&Javascript side,

  - `addEventlistener` is `addEventListener`.
  - When your script is used, please modify `document.getElementById("one").addEventListener("input",doThis);` to as follows. Because when   `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function)` is not used, an error occurs at `addEventListener`.

    ```
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
        document.getElementById("one").addEventListener("input",doThis);
      });
    ```
  - When `input` is used as the event type, when the inputted text is `130`, `1`, `13` and `130` are sent. By this, `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateAmount).getCost(oneCode)` is run 3 times. So I think that `change` might be suitable for this situation.
- At Google Apps Script side,

  - At `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openUrl(url);`, `openUrl` is `openByUrl`.
  - I think that in your script, `var position = ordersLis.indexOf(oneCode);` is `var position = ordersList.indexOf(oneCode);`.
  - In your script, `oneCode` of `getCost(oneCode)` is the string type.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

### Modified script:

#### HTML&Javascript side:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.getElementById("one").addEventListener("change", doThis);
  });

  function doThis() {
    var oneCode = document.getElementById("one").value;
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateAmount).getCost(oneCode);
  }

  function updateAmount(cost) {
    document.getElementById("two").value = cost;
  }
</script>

<body>
  <div>
    <input id="one" type="text">
    <label for="one">orders</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input disabled id="two" type="text">
    <label for="two">amount</label>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

- When `<script>###</script>` is bottom of HTML, I think that `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {})` is not required to be used.

#### Google Apps Script side:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('page');
}

function getCost(oneCode){
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1333t7lvECnmOcCnTE6gnn_RN1wrPckWpIETiPUjkUnU/edit#gid=0";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data = ws.getRange(1,1,ws.getLastRow(),2).getValues();
  var ordersList = data.map(function(r){ return r[0].toString(); });
  var amountList = data.map(function(r){ return r[1].toString(); });
  var position = ordersList.indexOf(oneCode);
  if(position > -1){
    return amountList[position];
  }
  return "not found";
}
```

### Usage:

- From your script, it seems that you are using Web Apps. **When you use this script, please copy and paste the above scripts to the script editor, and please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- When the Web Apps is opened, please input a value to the input box and push the enter key or remove the focus from the input box. By this, `addEventListener("change", doThis)` is executed and `doThis` is run.

### References:

- [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [openByUrl(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyurlurl)
- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)